# Access IE object through code, after it was created

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

Using this code to create an IE object and then check on it's 'STATE' . My question is how to access *this specific IE object* which I created in the beginning of my test script. How can I access it and check on it's 'state'?

**Code sample:**

```
dim IE As Object
dim my_link

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_link = < a valid URL>

IE.Navigate my_link

do While (IE.Busy Or (IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE))
do something...
wait 1
do_something else...
loop
' ------------
```

This browser is created once in the start of the test script. Then I have many actions performed on it. Actions that need to check browser ready_state.

Thank-you.

Comment: What do you mean by _how to access this specific IE object which I created in the beginning of my test script?_ You already have the reference to the Internet explorer object and you are already using it to know the state of the IE application

Comment: You named it `ie` (you could have called it anything) with this statement `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

Comment: This piece of code is inside a function. It is done only once, in the beginning of the test script. This code is run in UFT, an automation platform by HPE. The name IE, has no importance. Can be called by any name... The issue I have is that I need to use the method "busy". This works only an a IE object. So how would it be possible to work on the previous IE object that was created , somewhere in the beginning of my code...?